# How to modify @Inject getter (passed from AEM ) in interface

Tags: java, aem-6, htl

```
@Inject
String getGoToFavoritesButtonLink();
```

is in the interface and not class. I want to modify its value to be something like `getGoToFavoritesButtonLink().concat(".html");` so that URL can be externalized. How can this be done without any setter?

Java:

```
@Model(adaptables = org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL) 
public interface WebshopFavoriteListConfigModel {
@Inject 
String 
getGoToFavoritesButtonLink();
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="${model.webshopFavoriteListConfigModel.goToFavoritesButtonLink}"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code so we can better understand your problem?

Comment: @Model(adaptables = org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public interface WebshopFavoriteListConfigModel {@Inject String getGoToFavoritesButtonLink();}

Comment: In html,  <a href="${model.webshopFavoriteListConfigModel.goToFavoritesButtonLink}"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can set the extension using the `extension` HTL option:

```
<a href="${model.webshopFavoriteListConfigModel.goToFavoritesButtonLink @ extension='html'}">...</a>
```

You can review all [URI manipulation options in the HTL Specification](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#125-uri-manipulation).